# Mesh missing transparency when imported as fbx

Tags: textures, maya, unreal-engine4, fbx

I created a theme in maya, and exported it as fbx. However, as I imported it into UE4, I noticed the translucency property is not imported with the meshes. I got non-transparent windows in my models.

[model in maya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW7bY.jpg)

[model in unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKgYs.jpg)

Comment: I think this question is mostly for some 3d forums like ctalk, etc ..

Comment: Is it `translucency` or `transparency` property?